# Protractor e2e Tests Login Redirection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth, protractor, e2e-testing

Currently have a partial end-to-end test that enters a username/password and clicks 'sign in'.

It does that successfully, but concludes at a "thanks you're logged in" page, instead of being redirected to the 'account portal' or 'dashboard', the way it would if I logged in through the browser.\

New to this project but we are using OAuth.

**Main question: Does this sound like a need for http mocking?**

Further details:

spec.js

```
describe('login page', function() {
    browser.driver.get('http://url.path/login');
    it('should render login page', function() {

      // Checking the current url
      var currentUrl = browser.driver.getCurrentUrl();
      expect(currentUrl).toMatch('/login');
    });
    it('should sign in', function() {

      // Find page elements
      var userNameField = browser.driver.findElement(By.id('username'));
      var userPassField = browser.driver.findElement(By.id('password'));
      var userLoginBtn  = browser.driver.findElement(By.id('loginbtn'));

      // Fill input fields
      userNameField.sendKeys('test@user.com');
      userPassField.sendKeys('1234');

      // Ensure fields contain what we've entered
      expect(userNameField.getAttribute('value')).toEqual('test@user.com');
      expect(userPassField.getAttribute('value')).toEqual('1234');

      // Click to sign in - waiting for Angular as it is manually bootstrapped.
      userLoginBtn.click().then(function() {
        browser.waitForAngular();
        expect(browser.driver.getCurrentUrl()).toMatch('/success');
      }, 10000);
    });
});
```

If I quickly click on the testing window, I can see it successfully reaches the 'success' page - but it does not redirect to the dashboard (it redirects when you manually sign in, through the browser). How can I continue this test to remain signed in and access the dashboard like a user would?

// New to the project, angular and and protractor.

**EDIT - Summarizing this a bit:**

- I would like protractor to begin tests on the */login* page
- Protractor should find and fill out the username and password fields, then click Login
- Protractor successfully log in, to see a */thankyou* page, then immediately redirect to the user's */dashboard* page
- *Maybe I'm missing a step, do we need to manually redirect in Protractor tests?*

(When a user manually logs in through the browser, they don't see the */thankyou* page - it's a quick redirect to */dashboard* . Protractor does not reach the dashboard page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your post lacks information but I'll try to make an assumption:

I suspect that your "thanks you're logged in" page makes javascript redirect after a timeout.

So after you click "Login", the browser loads "thanks you're logged in" page, and since the second parameter to `.then()` does nothing, `browser.waitForAngular()` fails because there is no angular on that page.

You should try to use something like `browser.driver.wait()` with a reasonable timeout to detect url change (described here: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/610) and trigger `browser.waitForAngular()` after the browser get to `/success` page.

Comment: When I run the code from the solution on the page you linked - protractor says: "Failed: undefined is not a function". Looks like it fails at the 'compareCurrentUrl' function. A sample of how I used the function can be found here https://jsfiddle.net/s3tbfkwy/

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using an explicit wait?

```
    return browser.driver.wait(function() {
        return browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
            return /success/.test(url);
        });
    }, 10000);
```

Your code would be like that:

```
  // Click to sign in - waiting for Angular as it is manually bootstrapped.
  userLoginBtn.click();
  return browser.driver.wait(function() {
        return browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
            return /success/.test(url);
        });
  }, 10000);
```

Comment: This was helpful, except the return line should be changed to: return url === [DESIRED URL];